# Automatically sizing a set of buttons to match the largest

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a set of Windows Forms buttons with content that changes dynamically. I want to keep them in an array, all of the same size, with all of the buttons autosizing to stay the same size as each other and large enough for the one with the largest content, if that makes sense. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Try writing it yourself, then come back if you run into problems

Comment: Do you have a way to determine how large the largest one needs to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the benefit of `event` instead of looping through your buttons array like this:

```
public class Form1 : Form {
   public Form1(){
      InitializeComponent();
      //I suppose buttons is your buttons array defined somewhere.
      int m = 0;
      foreach (Button button in buttons)
        {
            Binding bind = new Binding("Width", this, "ButtonMaxWidth");
            bind.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.Never;//This is important
            button.DataBindings.Add(bind);        
            button.AutoSize = true;     
            if(button.Width > m) m = button.Width;
            button.SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                Button but = s as Button;
                if (but.Width > ButtonMaxWidth)
                {
                    but.DataBindings["Width"].WriteValue();
                } else but.Width = ButtonMaxWidth;
            };
        }
        ButtonMaxWidth = m;//Initialize the max width, this is done only once and you don't have to loop through your buttons to update the max width because it's done via the mechanism of `Binding` and `event`.
        //Try changing the Width of any button in your buttons array
        buttons[2].Width = 300;//if this > MaxWidth, all the buttons will change its Width to the new same MaxWidth, otherwise they will stay on the current MaxWidth.            
        //Try changing the Text of one of your buttons
        buttons[1].Text = "I love Windows Presentation Foundation";
   }
   public int ButtonMaxWidth {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I'd not thought of binding to the width. I probably need to look more closely at what I can do with bindings. Thanks!

Comment: @digitig in fact `Binding` can be replaced by some custom event (to notify when `ButtonMaxWidth` changes) but you have to create the event first and add event handler for it, ... Using `Binding` would be great and should be used for binding properties. It's used frequently in `WPF` and it's readable, maintainable. I think You should make familiar with it so that switching to `WPF` (if you haven't worked with WPF) would be easier.

Comment: Last time I looked at WPF I found it tried to force me to a UI style that I now recognise in Windows 8, and strongly resisted the UI style of Windows 7 and earlier. That's not what I or my clients want, so, unless WPF has changed significantly since its early versions, I'm more likely to migrate to a different platform than adopt WPF. Binding has a wider use in Windows Forms than I had realised, so I'll extend my use of it there.

Answer (score 2):

First set all buttons to AutoSize:

```
foreach (Button B in MyButtonArray)
{
    B.AutoSize = true;
}
```

Then set all contents:

```
foreach (Button B in MyButtonArray)
{
    B.Text = whatervercontent;
}
```

Then get largest button:

```
int MaxWidth = 0;
foreach (Button B in MyButtonArray)
{
    if (B.Width > MaxWidth) 
        MaxWidth = B.Width;
}
```

Then set the width, turning off the Autosize:

```
foreach (Button B in MyButtonArray)
{
    B.AutoSize = false;
    B.Width = MaxWidth;
}
```